# Does DRF Model serializer preserve the order in the list when creating multiple objects?

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I want to use `ModelSerializer` to create multiple objects.

If I have a list of the data for the objects as,

```
data = [{object_1_data},{object_2_data},...]
```

and when I use model serializer to create the objects as,

```
serializer = serializer(data=data, many=true)
if serializer.is_valid():
    objects = serializer.save()
```

Does the return `objects` list contain the objects in the same order as earlier?

```
objects = [object_1, object_2, ...]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes.

Example (in case on is needed):
Serializers must keep the object order, for DRF to keep ordering of results in their viewsets. Order is taken from the original queryset/list order.
Take the `list()` method of the DRF ListModelMixin:

```
class ListModelMixin:
    """
    List a queryset.
    """
    def list(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        queryset = self.filter_queryset(self.get_queryset())

        page = self.paginate_queryset(queryset)
        if page is not None:
            serializer = self.get_serializer(page, many=True)
            return self.get_paginated_response(serializer.data)

        serializer = self.get_serializer(queryset, many=True)
        return Response(serializer.data)
```

(Ordering is done in the queryset and not on the serializer's resulting data)

Comment: When (many=True) flag is added to a serializer, It becomes a child of the list serializer. Which then maintains the order. Link to List serializer implementaion.  https://github.com/encode/django-rest-framework/blob/19655edbf782aa1fbdd7f8cd56ff9e0b7786ad3c/rest_framework/serializers.py#L565